# How can I check read permission of /proc/*/* files?

Tags: linux, permissions, proc

Files in `/proc/` seem to be world-readable, but return permission denied:

```
$ ls -lh /proc/5589/smaps  
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 18 13:11 /proc/5589/smaps
$ cat /proc/5589/smaps 
cat: /proc/5589/smaps: Permission denied
```

I want to avoid reading such files, but `-r` check passes:

```
$ if [ -r /proc/5589/smaps ] ; then echo readable ; fi
readable
```

How do I check if the file is actually readable?

Comment: What distribution are you on? What are the mount options of `proc`in `etc/fstab`?

Comment: I'm on Mint; there's no separate mount for `/proc`, so it's included in `/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if cat /proc/5589/smaps 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null; then 
    echo readable ; 
fi
```

or to read less

```
if head -n 1 /proc/5589/smaps 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null; then 
    echo readable ; 
fi
```

**Update:**

I think you need to combine both checks in your script:
1) if [ -r /proc/5589/smaps ]
2) if cat /proc/5589/smaps 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null;

So that first you check file permissions and then check a result of reading a proc file. For example:

```
filename="/proc/5589/smaps"
if test -r "$filename" && cat "$filename" 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null; then
    echo readable
else
    echo not readable
fi
```

Comment: I linked your answer from https://github.com/nixsavy/shell-scripts/pull/3/commits/60909d60df39a88e956efab355ea1ec3b64fe5d5